# How to change the position of axis scale in R using persp3D() function from plot3D?

Tags: r, plot3d

I am plotting a surface plot using function `persp3D()`. However, I wanted the zero on my y-axis(k) scale to start at the same zero with my z-axis(R0). Currently, the zero on my y-axis(k) and x-axis(A) starts at the same point. I need the zero on the y-axis and z-axis to start at the same point instead in order to have better viewing direction. I attached two images, one is my result and another one is an example of what I desired the plot to be.
Below is my code as well.
[image: my result]

[image: example of desired plot]

```
library(plot3D)

lambda <- 1/12
sigma <- 0.4
gamma <- 0.4
beta <- 0.00006
c <-0.0034
m <- 0.056/12
mu <- 1

f <- function(x,y){(beta*(x*(m+lambda)/((m+c)*(m+lambda)+m*y))*sigma*gamma)/((m+sigma+c)*(m+mu+c))}
x <- seq(0,1000,10)
y <- seq(0,1,0.01)
z <- outer(x,y,f)

persp3D(x=x, y=y, z=z, 
        col.palette = heat.colors, 
        phi = 15, theta = 295, nticks=5,
        zlab="", ylab = "k", xlab="A", 
        xlim = c(0, 1000), 
        ylim = c(0, 1), 
        zlim = c(0, 3.5),
        box = TRUE, border = NA, shade = .4,ticktype="detailed",scale= TRUE, expand = 0.5)
par(xpd = TRUE)
text3D(0, 1.3, 1, expression(R[0]), add = T)
```

Comment: dont you just need to set the starting viewing angle, like `theta = 120`? and then `text3D(0, -2, 1, expression(R[0]), add = T)`

Comment: ahh thanks so much!